# Protocol Buffer Editor for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, intellij-plugin

I'm running with IntelliJ version 2019.2 Ultimate, *which is the version I purchased (i.e. perpetual license for this version)*.

And, I'm tyring to install a Protocol Buffer plugin for IDEA from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14004-protocol-buffer-editor

Since it would not install (not even available in the Marketplace from the IDE), I decided to try to build it from this source: https://github.com/jvolkman/intellij-protobuf-editor and I managed to build the plugin jar.

Tried to install it manually to the IDE but it wont accept the plugin (similar to all the jars from the release page)

**Is there a way to have Protocol Buffer plugin work with IntelliJ 2019.2 (and related versions)?**

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to install the outdated C++ plugin, I never found a solution for it. I'm guessing your license doesn't allow you to update IntelliJ?

Comment: @Mick yes can't update now that it has expired. Otherwise I will be running on evaluation version which is not great.

Comment: I filled an issue/feature request just in case: https://github.com/jvolkman/intellij-protobuf-editor/issues/52